# beautifulsoup not returning expected results?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to read a GIGANTIC file. Doing simple searches returns obviously incorrect results!

heres the code:

```
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.nhl.com/scores/htmlreports/20132014/PL020749.HTM')
html = data.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

a = soup.findAll('td')

print len(a)
```

this produces

```
2737
```

however just manually searching for `<td` in sublime text shows that there are `15562` `td` elements on this source code.

`td` is the easiest example. anything else i search for is also returning way less than expected.  Does beautifulsoup only parse so many lines then quits? Or am I doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I ran your code as is and I got the exact number of `td` element you mention, 15562. I suspect that you need to update your version of `lxml` or your version of beautiful soup to the latest version.. I have lxml 3.2.4 and BS 3.2.1

Comment: @qwwqwwq i just ran `sudo apt-get --purge remove python-bs4` and `pip uninstall beautifulsoup` and `pip install lmxl --upgrade` yet still getting 2737. I'm getting very annoyed with this. is there any where else a faulty beautifulsoup could be installed?

Comment: note that i ran this using python's default html parser and also got 2737, so i'm assuming it has to be an issue with beautifulsoup then

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: @qwwqwwq 2.7. i've removed BS4 every way i know how yet i can still import it

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you. Try a different parser with this way:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
```

This will solve your problem.